# Accessing elements of a rendered HTML page from Javascript launched by node

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I am rendering an HTML page from javascript. I need to refresh certain contents periodically. I kick-start my JS from node, I use sendFile() method to render HTML contents to my localhost. The question is how do I access the elements within the rendered contents?

One possible approach I am thinking is webscraping. I follow the sequence within my index.js as follows: readFile(myHtml) -> scrape & modify contents -> renderFile(myHtml).. is this the only method? Or do we have any elegant methods? I know there is a way in Angular, but I am using plain vanilla JS at the moment, and I want to do a quick fix.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did lot of research on my above question, as there were no answer, so finally found a correct solution to my problem. So the answer I am going to share is not a direct answer to above question, but overall solution I was looking for in the first place. I confess I didn't share my entire problem, I was just trying to get a quick fix to a roadblock on my way in previous approach.

I wanted to refresh my webpage periodically using access token which expires after a session. In my previous approach, I was using backend to handle both tasks obtaining token from Auth server and also refreshing my webpage. So, I loaded the html from backend and thought of refreshing it each time with fresh values, so I was able to scrape it, update it and had the fresh page ready to go. However, each refresh was failing because of res.send() or res.writeFile() methods were failing with "Err: headers already set, can't set headers again" error message.

So I looked at my architecture, and I realized it would be possbile to split the tasks between frontend and backend. So the page was refreshed by frontend script everytime using the token passed by backend, backend obtained fresh token before the session expired and passed it to fronend using socketio. There are several ways to pass values between fronend and backend, but I found it lot more convenient and we can use custom events as well.

So, the lesson I learnt from this is, "when the problem is so uncommon, re-look at your architecture".

Hope this piece of post helps someone in similar situation.